# joomla show articles in menu that are in the same category

Tags: joomla

If I have a vertical menu displaying via a module using the mod_mainmenu I can see categories within my sections by using the menu editor.

The only problem is that I want to show all the articles within a category in that menu as well, and since this isn't dynamic i'd have to add each article each time which would get frustrating.

is there a way to dynamically do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the latest news module and style it the same way as your menus with css.

With the latest news module you can set how many items to list and from which category too.

Comment: true, but it won't appear *in* the menu item on the left of the page which is the main thing i'm going for. perhaps i should use the latest news module as my menu moving forward then?

Comment: I understood that you want to show your latest articles just like your vertical menu on your website. You can do this with the latest news module as this can be positioned on a page and styles any way you want.

Comment: oops looks like my reply didn't get added. that sounds like the go, however can i tell the latest news module to display all the articles in the category that the current article i'm viewing is on?

Comment: Ok so what I did was ovveride the latest news module and run a query that gets the category Id of the current article and then gets all other articles in the same category and only display them. boom it worked.